# How can I most easily parse this HTTP response into JSON to then access responseText fields?

Tags: javascript, http

I'm trying to parse the plaintext that's returned from this URL -- https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace -- in order to read the IP address value. This is the code snippet I'm using for the request:

```js
ipAddress = $.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace', function(data) {
  return data;
});
```

When logged in browser console, the response looks like the following:

[image]

I've tried using `JSON.stringify()`, accessing `responseText` using `['responseText']`, as well as `.responseText`.. but no luck.

How can this response be parsed so that I can most easily access the `ip` value from within `responseText`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you provide any kind of context as to why this might not be considered a well formed question? ...instead of having me root around in the four links you provided? Thanks!

Comment: Note that `$.get` is async and `ipAddress` is not the `data` variable you return in your function.

Comment: You wrote _"I tried using...but no luck"_ but where is your code that you tried? We can't really help you fix your code if you don't show it to us. For example, what code is causing the output in the console? Are you logging `ipAddress` or `data`? It would be helpful if you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65752416/edit) to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on making the edit.

Comment: @Charles - I did, in that comment: *"Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a* picture *of text."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.get("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", function(data) {
  const [ ,ip ] = data.match(new RegExp("ip=" + "(.*)" + "\n"));
  console.log(ip);
});
```

**Outputs**

```
"2a01:cb18:362:2200:e90e:fb09:8445:6302"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse on carriage return or simply look for the ip= in the string or use a regex search it.

If you look at ipAddress.reponseText it's a carriage return delimited string.
so

```
var myip=ipAddress.responseText.split('\n');
console.log(myip[2]); 'the text ip=192.168.1.10  for example if it's always in the same position.
```

If it's not in the same position then look through the array to find it.

Answer (score 0):

its return document as response, so i'm not pretty clear about JSON, here some way

```js
const ipAddress = $.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace', function (data) {
  const arr = data.split("\n")
  const ip = arr.filter(v => v.includes("ip="))[0]
  console.log(ip.split("=")[1])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```